# How to get symmetric key generated by OpenSSL handshake in C++?

Tags: c++, ssl, networking, openssl, aes

I create SSL connection between client and server using OpenSSL in C++ like this (client side):

```
SSL *clientssl = SSL_new(ssl_client_ctx);
SSL_set_fd(clientssl, clientsocketfd);
SSL_connect(clientssl);
```

Now, I am able to communicate between hosts using TLS packets.

However, I would also like to send and receive pure UDP packets containing small, AES-encrypted parts from client to server. The idea is to use SSL symmetric key as AES key.

Is there a function like:

```
void SSL_get_symmetric_key(SSL *ssl, char *buffer);
```

that I can use in both client and server side?

Of course, I can generate AES key by myself and send it after handshake, but using existing key seems easier.

Comment: Don't reuse the same key. You can use DTLS to encrypt UDP traffic. Let DTLS perform its own handshake to negotiate its own key.

Comment: DTLS = [Datagram Transport Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security). OpenSSL has DTLS functions.

Comment: There also seems to be a mild misunderstanding of the TLS protocol. For that, see [Differences between the terms “pre-master secret”, “master secret”, “private key”, and “shared secret”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27131), [What is the purpose of four different secrets shared by client and server in SSL/TLS?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1139), et al.